# Pandas create dataframe from a dictionary of 2D arrays

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create a dataframe from a dictionary of 2D arrays such that each element in the dataframe is an array? For example, I would like `df.iloc[0]["A"]` below to return a `[0,0,0]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"A":np.zeros([100,3]), "B":np.zeros([100,3]), "C":np.zeros([100,3])}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
# print(df.iloc[0]["A"]) = [0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to accept them being Python lists instead of np.arrays, you can do this:

```
data = {"A": np.zeros([100,3]).tolist()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(df.iloc[0]["A"])
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k:x.ravel() for k,x in data.items()},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(100), np.arange(3)]))
```

Then `df.loc[0,'A']` gives you a series:

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```